# How to count multiple word occurrences in Unix coming after some pattern

Tags: python, linux, unix

```
FILE CONTENT:
2022-02-02 13:00:01 ERROR SINGAPORE
2022-02-02 13:00:01 ERROR HONGKONG
2022-02-02 13:00:01 ERROR SINGAPORE
2022-02-02 13:00:01 ERROR THAILAND
2022-02-02 13:00:01 ERROR HONGKONG
...
...
```

TOTAL SAY 800 ERRORS WITH 50+ DIFFERENT COUNTRIES

QUERY - count different countries based on pattern ERROR.

REQUIRED OUTPUT -

```
SINGAPORE - 2
HONGKONG - 2
THAILAND - 1
```

How to do above in Unix with single line command ?
I tried CUT but cannot count.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{++a[$4]}END{for (country in a){print country" - "a[country]}}' yourfile.txt
```

That captures each country into an array index/key and increments that key's value each time that country is found. Then it prints out the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '$3="ERROR"{cnt[$4]++}
END{for (e in cnt) print e, cnt[e]}' file
```

If you want `cut` to 'count' you can do:

```
cut -d " " -f 4 file | sort | uniq -c
```